# How to hide/enable UserControl in all xaml pages?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have an User control. That UserControl have some functionalities. I have called this usercontrol in my Common Resource Directory file. I am Inherit this Resource Directory page in all pages. This enables my user control in all my pages. what i want is, I want this usercontrol for Some particular page which i can set. This is my code.

Resource Directory file:

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UserControls">                   

<!-- Navigation AppBar -->

     <l:NavigationAppBarUserControl 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window1.xaml:

```
<src:WindowBase x:Class=""  
      xmlns:src="clr-namespace:ProjectOne"              
      Title="Window1">

   <Grid>
         //some functions...
   </Grid>
</src:WindowBase>
```

This will enable my user control. But this page, i want to hide my user conrol. But without removing (src:WindowBase).. how can i hide the UserControl here? Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

In WindowBase class create a property of type Visibility and bind the Visisbility of UserControl to it.

> WindowBase

```
public class WindowBase : Window
{
    public WindowBase(Visibility ucVisibility)
    {
        UCVisibility = ucVisibility;
    }

    public WindowBase() : this(Visibility.Visible) { }

    public Visibility UCVisibility { get; set; }
    //other stuff
}
```

> UC binding

```
        <l:NavigationAppBarUserControl 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Visibility="{Binding UCVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

> Now where you do not want it to show send Visibility.Collapsed in base constructor.

```
public partial class Window3 : WindowBase
{
    public Window3():base(Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: i already have a windoebase class file. there i used some other stuff. I am unable to use your windowbase  public WindowBase() : this(Visibility.Visible) { } code.

Comment: public class WindowBase : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       //some func }

Comment: I mean add this property to your WindowBase class , I doesnt mean to use this one. Add UCVisibility Property to it

Comment: I mean Create UCVisibility property in your WindowBase class